# Allow Incorrect Package Name in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I have some classes in my current project which have the wrong package declaration (they are in the wrong folder for their declared package.)

Unfortunately, fixing the problem by moving the class is not an option. Is there a way I can get eclipse to ignore the error?

Comment: Why is moving the class not an option? How does the code even compile?

Comment: What do you mean by wrong folder? Can you fix it by creating a new source folder?

Comment: Actually, the package name matching the folder structure is just a convention.

Comment: It's not in the language spec but it appears to be part of at least some implementations. http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html and

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fiddle with Eclipse's display in the "Errors/Warnings" section of preferences, but <s>Java requires that you have files in the correct folder to match their package, so it won't be able to build</s>

Comment: Actually, this is a requirement of Eclipse, not Java.

Comment: Where do I configure this in errors/warnings? I'm not seeing anything.

Comment: @SamBeran - did you find it?  I'm in the same boat here.

Answer (score 6):

If fixing the problem by moving the class is not an option, is fixing the problem by changing the declared package name an option?  If you can't do one of those two things, the code won't compile -- so this wouldn't be an Eclipse problem so much as a Java problem.

Comment: No, I can't change anything about the project at this time.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you're not going to be able to get the project to compile at all.  Is there anything you can change?

Comment: I'm assuming that the project compiles, or it would need to be changed.  There are all sorts of things that can be done in a build before `javac` is invoked, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the source folder for Eclipse at the right level?  The source folder for Eclipse should be at the level where the package folders start.  If there are multiple folders with separate package structures, each one would be it's own source folder.